# gnuplot, plotting time on x-axis

Tags: gnuplot

I have data in the following format in a text file. I want to print the time (hours, mins and secs) on the x-axis.  Each timestamp is on a separate line

```
00:00:05,1
00:00:15,0
01:05:23,1
07:45:00,0
23:21:22,1
```

Trying the following commands with gnuplot but time isn't printed on x-axis. I would like the time displayed in hours.

```
set datafile separator ","
set xdata time
set xrange["00:00:00":"24:00:00"]
set timefmt '%H:%M:%S
plot 'data.txt' using 1:2 with boxes
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I formatted your code to make it more readable. Code blocks are marked with four spaces at the beginning. Also, there is no need to write your name, since a signature appears automatically.

Answer (score 1):

The `set timefmt` settings are used only for reading the data file. If you don't provide an explicit output format, timedate is assumed automatically. Use `set xtics format '%H:%M:%S'` to set an explicit output format. Also, parsing of the `set xrange` strings can be done properly only after you have set the time format:

```
set datafile separator ","
set xdata time
set timefmt '%H:%M:%S
set xrange["00:00:00":"24:00:00"]
set xtics format '%H:%M:%S'
plot 'data.txt' using 1:2 with boxes
```

Comment: HI Christoph.  Really ppreciate your help. That worked. I would like to display the data as on/off format. E.g. at 00:00:05, unit switches to ON (1) and stays at 1 until 00:00:15 when it goes to 0. It then stays at 0 until 01:05:23 until it switches back on again and so forth. What would be the best format for this?

Comment: Use `plot 'data.txt' using 1:2 with steps` for this, your current data format should be fine.

Comment: Hi Christoph, Just did that and it worked. Finally, I would like to file the steps a red colour. Have you a one liner for this?

Comment: To fill the steps, use the `fillsteps` style, `set style fill solid noborder; plot 'data.txt' using 1:2 with fillsteps lc rgb 'red'`.

Comment: Thanks Christoph. That is super. Much appeciate your help. Mike